# Does qgis2web plugin support heatmap symbology for a point layer?

Tags: qgis, heat-map, qgis2web

I am trying to create a web page from QGIS using qgis2web plugin. I have a point layer and when I render its symbology as *single symbol*, it gets successfully exported to a web page when I used leaflet. But when I use "*heatmap*" symbology for the point layer, I don't get it as a web page. I wanted to know if heatmap symbology is supported for qgis2web plugin. Or is there a workaround by editing the html or css files generated?[image]

I have shared the layer view as it appears in QGIS.